# Ignoring missing values in calculation

Tags: r, na

For example,

```
> a<-c(1:5)
> b<-c(10-15)
> a-b
[1]  6  7  8  9 10
```

Here, how to skip NAs, if present in one (a or b) or both (a and b).

Preferably, how to do this without any complex conditional statement?

Comment: you can use `na.omit`, take a look at `?na.omit`

Comment: @Jilber: Thank you, `na.omit(a-b)` did the business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> a<-c(1:5)
> b<-c(10-15)
```

Just use `na.omit(a-b)`